# O365 Outlook Add-In fails to load

Tags: outlook-addin

We have a Custom Outlook Addin. Which is frequently giving

```
"Add-in error: This add-in may not load properly, but you can still try to start it."
```

After couple of retries it started working and it is happening on every first load when I click the add-in.

What could cause this issue ?

Our manifest file is fine and the site is also working fine in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure add-in's pages reference the `office.js` library and include an `Office.initialize` handler.

Take a look at the [Understanding the JavaScript API for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office) section for more information.